# Do I need to start the session at any controller where I need to access it?

Tags: php, symfony, session

I have this code in the `indexAction` of a controller and that index is a start point for a process (include call to several controllers through Ajax):

```
$session = $request->getSession();
$currentData = [];
$session->set('currentData', $currentData);
```

Now suppose that I need to set a new value for `currentData` in another controller, I'm doing right now as:

```
$session = $request->getSession();

// get currentData from session for not override the values
$currentData = $session->get('currentData');

// sets the new value
$currentData['newValue'] = 1;

// save the var again and override currentData session
$session->set('currentData', $currentData);
```

Regarding this and as title says the question is easy: Do I need to start (call `$session = $request->getSession()` all the time whenever I need access to session) the session at any controller where I need to access it? Exists any best way to achieve this or I'm the one did all wrong? Any advice?

*NOTE*: I forgot to mention I'm talking and working with Symfony 2.6.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to, however it is recommended. [From the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html):

> While it is recommended to explicitly start a session, a session will actually start on demand, that is, if any session request is made to read/write session data.

You do need to get the `Session` container by using `$session = $request->getSession()`, `$session = $this->get('session')`, or `$session = new Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session();`. This is not the same as starting a session and there's really no difference between the three ways.

This applies to any Symfony 2.x version.